# How to change an objects properties by touching it on mobile (UNITY) (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm really new to game dev and stack overflow so i'm sorry if I've missed something.

I've looked everywhere but can't find a solution to my question.

So, i'm making a 2D **mobile** game through unity. Objects (sprites) are falling down using a rigid body and i want the user to be able touch the objects that are falling down which will trigger an animation or color change and add a particle explosion.

The issue is i'm having trouble trying to figure out how to actually get the user to touch the sprite and trigger an event ( I have no idea how to code touch input on the object) i've watched youtube tutorials such as brackeys and a bunch of other videos and through the unity documentation but they don't explain exactly what i need and all make joysticks which is no help for me.

From the research i've done i've found quite a few people talk about raycasting, should i be looking more into that?

Thank you everyone for your help, you've no idea how much i appreciate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a script to those objects with the method OnMouseDown which works for both mouse and touch, then trigger whatever event you what. Before exporting to Android test it on your own PC. They also need a collider.

Comment: I'll try this now, thank you so much for replying so fast :)

Comment: Sorry, gonna have to start again because my project is everywhere, i'll try this soon and let you know how i go. If anyone has any other solutions in the mean time pls let me know. Thanky ou!

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you so much, oh my god. I owe you my first born. <3